# Pass string array to NDK JNI method

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying following code inside cpp file to receive arraylist from java file. Here is the code

```
jobjectArray trackables;
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_putitout_buck_VideoPlayback_setTrackables(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject trackables_)
{

    // use the Array list
    jclass  ArrayList_class = env->FindClass( "java/util/ArrayList" );

    // to conver jobject to jstring
    jmethodID caster = env->GetMethodID(ArrayList_class, "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    // get two methods
    jmethodID Get_method            = env->GetMethodID( ArrayList_class, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object" );
    jmethodID Size_method           = env->GetMethodID( ArrayList_class, "size", "()I" );

    // call java.lang.ArrayList.get()
    int NumElts = env->CallIntMethod(trackables_, Size_method);

    // allocate output array
    jclass objClass = env->FindClass("java/lang/String");
    trackables = env->NewObjectArray(NumElts, objClass, 0);

    // fetch all the items
    for(int i = 0 ; i < NumElts ; i++)
    {
        // call java.lang.ArrayList.get(int index) method
        // Not sure about the parameter passing here
        jobject Tmp = env->CallObjectMethod(trackables_, Get_method, i);

        jstring Str = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(Tmp, caster);

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "%s", Str);

        // get the length
        int StrLen = env->GetStringLength(Str);

        env->SetObjectArrayElement(trackables, i, Str);
    }
}
```

Following is the code I am declaring in java file

```
public native void setTrackables(ArrayList<String> trackables);
```

Following is in the log.

```
10-24 17:45:44.555: W/dalvikvm(27400): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
10-24 17:45:44.555: W/dalvikvm(27400):              in Lcom/putitout/buck/VideoPlayback;.setTrackables:(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V (GetMethodID)
10-24 17:45:44.555: W/dalvikvm(27400): Pending exception is:
10-24 17:45:44.555: E/dalvikvm(27400): VM aborting
10-24 17:45:44.560: A/libc(27400): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

Comment: do I need to import anything in cpp file?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using JNI to convert an ArratList of objects into an array of strings? Better do that in Java - much cleaner code - and pass the array of strings to JNI.

That said, LogCat says one of your Java method calls is causing an exception. It does not say which one. To debug, insert a check after every CallXXXMethod:

```
if(env->ExceptionOccurred())
{
    __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TRACKERS", "Error in (MethodName)");     
    env->ExceptionDescribe();
}
```

Also, "any help?" comment is not constructive. Please don't rush the community. This is a free service, no one here **owes** you an answer.